# zlib: how to lock file?

Tags: multithreading, zlib

I need to read a file in several threads, and I need to ensure that only one thread is reading the file at one time. For non-compressed files I use

```
void Process_File(FILE* Input_File)
{
    flockfile(Input_File);
    ....Do stuff
    funlockfile(Input_File);
}
```

is there any way to lock a file in zlib. i.e. if `Input_File` is of type `gzFile` how do I lock it. My current idea is to open the file as usual and lock it during the zlib routines. Will this assure that the file will be locked for reading by other threads using zlib?

Comment: If nobody is writing to the file, there is no need to lock the file.  Multiple threads can read from the same file simultaneously without any issues.

Comment: (just be sure to open the file separately in each thread -- i.e. don't try to share a single file-handle pointer across multiple threads)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Thanks for the tip! I need to read 4 consecutive lines from the file. Therefore I need to assure that other threads do not access the file during this time.

Comment: the current-position state is stored with the file handle, not with the file itself.  Therefore thread A reading from the file will not affect thread B in any way, because they have separate file handles and thus separate current-position variables.